# Get my tabpanel component but cant use add to add a tab

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i have a tabpanel in view makemoney.js. and i want write code in my controller addtab.js . but i have encounter a error in my chrome console.

and i have found that the Ext.ComponentQuery.query('itemId')[0] return type is component,but the tabpanel's add method must make the container.add is container.is it the cause.if right, what can i change

my makemoney.js code:

```
Ext.define('ylp2p.view.makemoney',{
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'makemoney',
requires: [
    'Ext.Toolbar',
    'Ext.tab.Panel'
],

config:{
    layout: 'vbox',
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: '111'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'tabpanel',//-----here is my tappanel
            itemId: 'tabfirst',
            flex: 1,
            tabBar: {
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
});
```

and my controller code:

```
Ext.define('ylp2p.controller.addtab',{
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
launch: function(){
    var moneytab = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.makemoney #tabfirst')[0];
    //i think i get the component alerdy
    var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        html: 'This will be added to a Container'
    });
    //and write a panel
    moneytab.add([myPanel]);
    //make the panel into the tap.i dont why it not work
}
});
```

my console in chrome put an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#doAdd] Adding a card to a tab container without specifying any tab configuration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work

```
var moneytab = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('makemoney #tabfirst')[0];
    var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        html: 'This will be added to a Container',
        title: 'Yourtitle'
    });
    //and write a panel
    moneytab.add(myPanel);
```

Comment: i have try before. it will say--Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#doAdd] Adding a card to a tab container without specifying any tab configuration

Comment: As per your Information I have edited my code. You can use that.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not correct, that's the reason of the error.

`var moneytab = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.makemoney #tabfirst')[1];`

`moneytab = undefined;`

Use this instead:

`var moneytab = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tabpanel #tabfirst')[0];`

Comment: i have try before. it will say--Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#doAdd] Adding a card to a tab container without specifying any tab configuration